# NSUserDefaults resetting to registeredDefaults

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsuserdefaults

I have a default called *showsguidelines* which is whether or not a user wants guidelines to be displayed while dragging items in a document.

Setting and querying the defaults using my two helper methods below works great for the life of the application. But as soon as the application is restarted I get weird issues.

---

What happens is this.

1. I set *showsguidelines* to be **NO**.
2. I re-launch the application.
3. After registerDefaults is called I verify that *showsguidelines* is still **NO**. (**[AppPreferences registerDefaults]** is called from within **initialize** in the app delegate.)
4. The next time that I query for *showsguidelines* I get **YES** (which is the registeredDefault).
5. The odd thing is I have an NSMenuItem bound to *showsguidelines* and it always respects the correct (expected) value. (**NO** in this case).

---

I have already verified that the value is never being set to **YES** anywhere else in the application by adding an observer to **[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]** for the key *showsguidelines*. It is also not a synchronization issue because I have verified on app launch that the value is correct.

Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

```
// AppPreferences.m
#import "AppPreferences.h"

@implementation AppPreferences

+ (void)registerDefaults {

    NSURL *defaultPrefsFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"DefaultPreferences"
                                                      withExtension:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *defaultPrefs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:defaultPrefsFile];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultPrefs];

    NSLog(@"-register: %@", [PCAppPreferences showsGuidelines] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
}


#pragma mark - showsGuidelines
+ (BOOL)showsGuidelines {

    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"showsguidelines"];
}

+ (void)setShowsGuidelines:(BOOL)showsGuidelines {

    NSLog(@"-set showsguidelines: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"showsguidelines"] ? @"YES" : @"NO");

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:showsGuidelines forKey:@"showsguidelines"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

@end


// Called on App Launch
2014-03-26 14:27:53.035 AppName[30636:303] -set showsguidelines: NO
2014-03-26 14:27:53.035 AppName[30636:303] -register: NO
// Called shortly afterward
2014-03-26 14:27:58.324 AppName[30636:303] -set showsguidelines: YES
2014-03-26 14:27:58.325 AppName[30636:303] -set showsguidelines: YES
2014-03-26 14:27:58.342 AppName[30636:303] -set showsguidelines: YES
```

Comment: I have this exact problem with my app, Cog. I know it is quitting properly. Settings are already saved. Yet, randomly, on any macOS older than Big Sur (I support down to High Sierra), it will randomly reset to registeredDefaults on startup. This is observed noticeably as the enabled playlist columns and column sizes resetting to defaults after two or three restarts.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you actually quit the application, rather than just "Run" an updated version from Xcode. Otherwise the defaults are never written out. So you start the app with no default (which defaults to `NO`) rather than an actual `NO` default. So when you register the defaults, it sees there is no default for that name, and now the registered default takes over and it becomes `YES`.

You can always use the command line `defaults read my.app.identifier` to check on started defaults.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But that is not the issue. The 'NO' I   log out after registering the defaults should be 'YES' on first launch if nothing is saved (it is specified in my DefaultPreferences.plist). Regardless, I did just try your suggestion and Quit the application and then ran the application from disk (not Xcode). But the same thing was happening.